# Manage GCP project credentials through API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to list all my GCP projects information through API (REST).
I can get basic information thanks to this API: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/apis , but I would like to gather the credentials details for the projects.

[image]

I can retrieve Google services accounts, but no API Key or OAuth 2.0 Client IDs. I could not find the relevant API documentation page. I'm browsing the documentation https://cloud.google.com/apis#section-7 , but either it's not in here or I don't understand how to proceed. I'm working with the REST API as the idea is to gather those information through Google Apps Script, but if there is documentation / library on another language I would also have a look.

Comment: This is an extremely limited api.  To my knowledge this information is not available.

Comment: In my experience I agree with @DaImTo but I found https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ to point you in the right direction these are the libraries for Google API's in a lot of different programming languages.

Comment: My answer here will provide additional resources for OAuth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69501577/8016720 This command will list API Keys which means there is an API: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/api-keys/list Add the command line option to see the REST API calls: --log-http

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client IDs can't be created or managed via API. An exception is if you're creating clients for IAP -- then you can use the [IAP API](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.brands.identityAwareProxyClients).

To manage API Keys, you can use the [API Keys API](https://cloud.google.com/api-keys/docs/reference/rest).