# Programmatically create GCE OAuth2 Web App credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

My company has a standard format for web apps, and I'm building a tool that programmatically provisions resources for new ones. The apps have federated login via Google, so I need to create a new OAuth2 web app clientId within Google/GCE. It can be done manually from the Credentials page [like this](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en), but I'd like to remove all manual steps from app setup.

So far I haven't been able to find any API endpoints or SDK functions that would allow me to create a new app, set its redirect url, etc. I have found the [service account credentials API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest), but as far as I can tell that does not include functionality to provision new OAuth apps.

Is there an API I'm missing that can do CRUD operations on OAuth credentials/clientIds? Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: See my comments here plus the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69990634/8016720

Comment: I ended up giving up finding an API-driven solution here, and automated it using a headless browser